# Creating new ImageViews in JavaFX and Scenebuilder

Tags: java, javafx, imageview, fxml, scenebuilder

I am going to give it another try... I am new to Scenebuilder and I am trying to make a photo gallery for my project! I have added what I wanted, that is a ImageView with a Image that is selected from FileChooser... But now I would like to get an advice how to save this one and create a new each time the addPhoto button is pressed, and not overwrite the one that I already have in the ImageView. here is my code for the addPhoto button:

```
@FXML

public void initialize(ActionEvent e) throws Exception{


        addPhotos.setOnAction(event -> {
            FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
            File file = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
           pic = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
           if(pic != null) {
             ImageView  imgView = new ImageView(pic);

           }

             imgView.setImage(pic);

    });
```

FXML Code:

```
    <BorderPane prefHeight="737.0" prefWidth="934.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="legioDesk.GalleryController">
   <top>
      <Button fx:id="addPhotos" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#initialize" text="addPhotos" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </top>
   <center>
      <TilePane fx:id="tp" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <ImageView fx:id="imgView" fitHeight="306.0" fitWidth="378.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
         </children>
      </TilePane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: "The ImageView is in a TilePane". But it's not; at least not from the code you posted. And this code won't "overwrite" anything. Create and post a [mre].

Comment: I have a BorderPane with a TilePane which contains the ImageView

Comment: But you don't. You create an `ImageView`. You don't put it in anything.

Comment: I am trying to add the FXML Code for you to see but I somehow can't manage... Sorry, I am sloppy since I rarely posted on SO.

Comment: Nothing in the FXML will make what you are claiming true. The `ImageView` is created right there in your controller. You don't add it to any container.

Comment: @James_D they didn't format the code, so the fxml was being truncated.

Comment: @matt The claim is still not true.

Comment: @James_D some of what they said is true that you refuted. Eg. They *do* have a border pane and tile pane. Anyways, I see you caught on and answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new `ImageView` in your event handler, but you never do anything with it, so it is just discarded.

Note that both `ImageView`s have the same variable name: the one you create (and discard) is scoped to the `if` block, so the one you reference outside the block is the one you define in the FXML file.

So your code does

```
@FXML

public void initialize(ActionEvent e) throws Exception{


    addPhotos.setOnAction(event -> {
        FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
        File file = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        pic = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
        if(pic != null) {
           // Create a new image view, containing the selected image
           // (but do nothing with it)
           ImageView  imgView = new ImageView(pic);

        }
        // now update the existing ImageView (from the FXML file) with
        // the chosen image:
        imgView.setImage(pic);

    });
}
```

What you want to do (I'm guessing, as you didn't explain very clearly the desired behavior) is to add the new image view to the tile pane:

```
@FXML

public void initialize(ActionEvent e) throws Exception{


    addPhotos.setOnAction(event -> {
        FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
        File file = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        pic = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
        if(pic != null) {
           ImageView  imgView = new ImageView(pic);
           imgView.setFitWidth(306);
           imgView.setFitHeight(378);
           imgView.setPreserveRatio(true);
           tp.getChildren().add(imgView);
        }
    });
}
```

and of course you don't need the Image View in the FXML file:

```xml
<BorderPane prefHeight="737.0" prefWidth="934.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="legioDesk.GalleryController">
   <top>
      <Button fx:id="addPhotos" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#initialize" text="addPhotos" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </top>
   <center>
      <TilePane fx:id="tp" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
      </TilePane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: yes, I am trying to make a new ImageView each time I press the addPhoto button... I will try the code in a few and give u feedback! thanks again!

Comment: worked perfectly ! of course now I have to work on the layout, have the images displayed in the same size and find a nice and fancy way to do it, also I would like to save them in a ListView.... but for now I will work on his what you provided, and I thank you once again!

Answer (score 1):

Okay since you say the single image version works and now you want to add a new image. Grab your TilePane, get the children, and add your image view.

```
pic = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
if(pic != null) {
    ImageView  nextView = new ImageView(pic);
    tp.getChildren().add(nextView);
}
//delete this it is changing the original one.
//imgView.setImage(pic);
```

This might work, but I cannot test it because you have not provided enough code.